# Is there a reason why the Konoha village gates in Naruto are really big?

Tags: naruto

The gates kind of looked like a weakness too me since summons can get in and destroy the village if they are caught off guard or the gates are not closed in time. Even if the gates are closed gates are very easy to break and since it is so big it would be a weakness in my opinion due to the summons. The reason why I see the gates as a weakness is since the wall is thicker and made out of tougher material, hopefully.

Comment: How can you say that the gates are very weak? Was how they're made discussed in the manga/anime? Because as far as I can recall, it was never discussed. How do you know the walls are tougher? Was it even mentioned? Also, how do you know that the guards can be caught off-guard by intruders? Are there only a few shinobi in patrol? Do you know there exact number or the jutsu they use to be able to say that they cannot react or will be overwhelmed by an enemy getting in? There seems to be many assumptions in the situation you are trying to describe in your question.

Comment: I took the assumption that the gates are weak from attack on titans since their gates were proven weak and that is the reason the titans got in. Not saying the gate is weak, it just doesn't seem like a good defence and I can't figure out why the gate was built that big. I just assumed the walls are strong since they look thick. No clue about jutsu, I'm just a noob who wrote to much to a simple question and doesn't know much 'bout Naruto. I will defiantly say I am assuming things.

Comment: If I were to speculate, I'd say the gate is mainly for accessibility. How else are visitors from other villages or people traveling to other villages go out of Konohagakure? Never have I heard of a village, fictional or real life, that is only surrounded by walls and has no gate. It could also be to keep wild animals out since if I recall correctly, Konohagakure is surrounded by a forest. It doesn't really matter if shinobi can easily destroy it. I mean, I doubt that there'd be no patrols on either side of the walls surrounding the village.

Comment: If intruders can easily get in, why destroy the gate in the first place? And if it's harder to get in, I doubt they would knock on the enemy's front door. It would make sense that the protection on the gate would be very heavy so I'm not sure they would go that way, either. Regarding its size, it could be for aesthetic purposes. I mean, who knows? Kishimoto never really discussed it in the manga.

Comment: Although there are usually patrols, thats not the main bulk of Konohagakures security. Its is revealed later on that their main security font is the [Konoha Barrier team](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Konoha_Barrier_Team). @W.Are So assuming a Ninja is able to best the guards at the gate, their chakra would automatically be detected by the barrier team